# Confusing "Your last flag was declined..." message

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, declined-flags, flag-history

Just had the following message when attempting to flag an answer.

> Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

I clicked on the "review" link in the message and it showed my flagging history. The three most recent flags shown there are Jul 5 at 7:36 helpful, Jul 3 at 15:30 helpful and Jul 3 at 12:04 declined. So my most recent two flags have been deemed helpful and the next oldest was declined. The message appears to be wrong.

Perhaps the message should say

> Recently one of your flags was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

Comment: Was the flag declined after the helpful ones?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I believe that the youngest two flags were accepted as helpful within a few hours of being raised. The third declined flag has only recently been declined.

Comment: Alternatively, the message could say "Your most recently addressed flag was declined..." as that is exactly what the message is trying to say.

Comment: Related to this, I noticed that you also still get this message if you already reviewed the declined flag (i.e. went to the flag history, clicked on the link to the answer you flagged, etc). So it's asking me to review something that I already reviewed in detail.

Comment: @psubsee2003 You suggested words also make sense. The current words are not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now reads: "Your recent flag was declined..."

See also: [Your last flag was declined - no it wasn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281152/your-last-flag-was-declined-no-it-wasnt/323063#323063)