# "Your previous flag was rejected"

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

What is the true text of this warning? (It's difficult to reproduce it.) Is [the text of this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266660/confusing-your-last-flag-was-declined-message) correct?

Does it appear *every time* after a flag is rejected?

Comment: No, it only appears AFAIK if a couple of flags are rejected within a 7 days period. I think this [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268573/578411) from Shog9 explains it.

Answer (score 6):

The text depends on how many flags you raised in the last seven days, and how many of them were rejected. The full list is explained in [this Meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405), but here is a summary:

- Fewer than ten flags, when the last *processed* flag was declined:

> Your recent flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

- Ten or more flags, 10-25% of them declined:

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!

- 10 or more flags, >= 25% of them declined:

> Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please review them instead of flagging this post!